# Do I understand this Strategy Pattern correctly?

Tags: c#, xna-4.0, strategy-pattern

In my previous question, I've been taught that the below code is an example of the Strategy Pattern. The line `_player.Draw(spriteBatch, _context);` in particular.

I don't see the difference between that line and the one below it, aside from the former being an extra method call.

Could someone explain me why I wouldn't just use the second call right to the `_drawHugeContext` and (gasp) delete `Draw()` from the `Player` class? Is this example too simple and is there a situation where the former would be much better?

```
public class Arena
{
   Player _player;
   IPlayerContext _drawHugeContext;

   public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
   {
      _player.Draw(spriteBatch, _drawHugeContext);
      _drawHugeContext.Draw(spriteBatch, _player);
   }
}

public class Player
{
    public int Percentage { get; private set; }
    [...] //A few more fields

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, IPlayerContext context)
    {
        context.Draw(spriteBatch, this);
    }
}

public class IPlayerContext
{
    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Player player)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(player.Percentage);
        [...] //A few more fields drawn from player
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using [strategy patterns](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy), but probably you do not yet understand why and how to use them. Let me give you a very simple example.

Let's say you have a set of objects and you want to sort them. The problem is: how do you specify the sort order? In .Net this is typically done by passing a lambda or a class which knows how to compare two of those objects to the "Sort" method, e.g.

```
var sorted = MyObjects.Sort((a,b) => a.Id > b.Id);
```

This allows you to decouple the logic of how to generically sort a list to the logic of how to order two elements of a specific set.

In your case `SpriteBatch` is the strategy that is injected in the calls, so that your object structure does not need to know, exactly, how to draw stuff.

I think you can use the example above to restructure your code effectively.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its a great example.  In answer to your questions:

1)The example doesn't show how strategies are selected. As SpriteBatch is already pre-determined.  This would help the example be more complete.

2)Calling draw, directly on player, adds an unnecessary level of indirection and it's not immediately apparent where/how this would be better.

There are plenty of examples out there but I have included an example of the Strategy pattern I have used  and which I first encountered in "Design Patterns in C#" by Steven Metsker (an excellent C# book of GoF patterns). I prefer this to the the wiki or doFactory  variations, but they are also good alternatives. This might help your understanding.

Lets say you have an insurance package which relies upon the generation of a quote, based upon customers' risk factors.

The insurance package will utilise a quoting engine to do this.

Firstly, define an interface with a method  defining the strategic operation to be shared by all strategies.

The public face of the quoting engine strategy is represented by the interface:

```
public interface IQuoteEngineStrategy
{
     decimal QuoteMeHappy(int riskDetails) 
}
```

And given 2 example concrete implementations

```
public class OnlineQuoteEngineStrategy : IQuoteEngineStrategy
{
    public decimal QuoteMeHappy(Customer c) { // online related retrieval } 
}

public class OfflineQuoteEngineStrategy : IQuoteEngineStrategy
{
   public decimal QuoteMeHappy(Customer c) { // offline related retrieval } 
}
```

The QuoteEngine decides upon dishing out a selected strategy based upon things in the customer. Here, age is the deciding factor.

```
public class QuoteEngine 
{

    public static IQuoteEngineStrategy GetQuotingEngine(Customer c) 
    {
        if (c.Age < 25 )
        {
           return new OnlineQuoteEngineStrategy();
        }
        else
        {
           return new  OfflineQuoteEngineStrategy();
        }
    }
```

}

Lastly, an InsurancePackage uses a QuoteEngine, passing in some information for the QuoteEngine to select its strategy and call the strategic operation initially identified.

```
public class InsurancePackage 
{

  public decimal RiskQuote(Customer c)
  {
       return QuoteEngine.GetQuotingEngine(c).QuoteMeHappy(c);
  }
}
```

Strategy pattern hides consumers from the implementation and selection of a particular strategy.

It allows strategic decisions to be made away from the consumer. As well as this each Concrete Strategy can act as an Adapter to disparate external dependencies.

Another benefit is that additional strategies can be added without InsurancePackage needing to be changed meaning the QuoteEngine adheres to single responsiblity principle (SRP)  and InsurancePackage the open/closed principle  (open for extension closed for modification.  (Checkout out uncle Bob Martin and SOLID principles of design too)